# Enable access from Azure DevOps to a keyvault and AllowAccessFrom only PrivateLink

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

Hoping to connect form the Azure DevOps portal to a keyvault with private link enabled and no access to other networks. Right now, when connecting the variable group to the keyvault i'm able to see the keyvault but not the contents of the secrets/certs/keys. It just times out, Do I need to add the Azure DevOps IPs to the keyvault access list? Where do I find these IPs? I have a listing of IPs by service tag but Azure DevOps does not show as a separate service. Any help would be great.

Comment: [Microsoft Azure Datacenter IP Ranges](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=41653), you need search the IP address via your org region, In addition, It will be deprecated in the near future.
, please check this blog [New IP address ranges with Service Tags for Azure DevOps Services](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/new-ip-address-ranges-with-service-tags-for-azure-devops-services/).
By the way, did you refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/private-link-service) to create Azure Key Vault with Azure Private Link?